# My TableView only lists the last item in my itemArray?

Tags: ios, swift

I have four items in my itemArray, but my TableView only lists my last appended item, and it lists it first. However, I can check and uncheck the three rows below the first row that actually has a text.

[image]

```
    import UIKit

class ToDoListViewController: UITableViewController {

    var itemArray = [Item]()
    
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let newItem = Item()
        newItem.title = "Find Mike"
        itemArray.append(newItem)
        
        let newItem2 = Item()
        newItem.title = "Buy Eggos"
        itemArray.append(newItem2)

        let newItem3 = Item()
        newItem.title = "Destroy Demongorgon"
        itemArray.append(newItem3)
        
        let newItem4 = Item()
        newItem.title = "RockOn!"
        itemArray.append(newItem4)
        
        
//        if let items = defaults.array(forKey: "ToDoListArray") as? [String] {
//            itemArray = items
//      }
    }

//MARK: - TableView Datasource Methods
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemArray.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoItemCell", for: indexPath)
        
        let item = itemArray[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = item.title
        
        cell.accessoryType = item.done ? .checkmark : .none
        
        return cell
    }
    
//MARK: - TableView Delegate Methods
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //print(itemArray[indexPath.row])
        
        itemArray[indexPath.row].done = !itemArray[indexPath.row].done
        
        tableView.reloadData()
        
         tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    //MARK: - Add New Items
    
    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        var textField = UITextField()
    
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Todoey Item", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Item", style: .default) { (action) in
            //what will happen once the user clicks the add item
            
            let newItem = Item()
            newItem.title = textField.text!
            
            self.itemArray.append(newItem)
            
            self.defaults.set(self.itemArray, forKey: "ToDoListArray")
            
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
        alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "Create new item"
            textField = alertTextField
        }
        
        alert.addAction(action)
        
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    }    
}
```

StackOverflow say I need more of a description... I think this says it all... This is for a Udemy iOS series...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have used same instance for set item name. Change your viewDidLoad method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let newItem = Item()
    newItem.title = "Find Mike"
    itemArray.append(newItem)
    
    let newItem2 = Item()
    newItem2.title = "Buy Eggos"
    itemArray.append(newItem2)
    
    let newItem3 = Item()
    newItem3.title = "Destroy Demongorgon"
    itemArray.append(newItem3)
    
    let newItem4 = Item()
    newItem4.title = "RockOn!"
    itemArray.append(newItem4)
    
    
    //        if let items = defaults.array(forKey: "ToDoListArray") as? [String] {
    //            itemArray = items
    //      }
}
```

Comment: That was it. I wascompletely blind to those numbers. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

check this and it's working, Your code after some slight edits:

```
import UIKit
class Item {
    var title: String
    var done: Bool
    
    init(itemTitle: String, itemStatus: Bool) {
        title = itemTitle
        done = itemStatus
    }
}
class ToDoListViewController: UITableViewController {

  var itemArray = [Item]()
  
  let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      addItemsToArray()
      
      
//        if let items = defaults.array(forKey: "ToDoListArray") as? [String] {
//            itemArray = items
//      }
  }

    //MARK: - add Items
    func addItemsToArray(){
        let newItem = Item(itemTitle: "Find Mike", itemStatus: false)
          itemArray.append(newItem)
          
        let newItem2 = Item(itemTitle: "Buy Eggos", itemStatus: false)
          itemArray.append(newItem2)

        let newItem3 = Item(itemTitle: "Destroy Demongorgon", itemStatus: false)
          itemArray.append(newItem3)
          
        let newItem4 = Item(itemTitle: "RockOn!", itemStatus: false)
          itemArray.append(newItem4)
    }
//MARK: - TableView Datasource Methods
  
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return itemArray.count
  }
  
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoItemCell", for: indexPath)
  
    cell.textLabel?.text = itemArray[indexPath.row].title
      
    cell.accessoryType = itemArray[indexPath.row].done ? .checkmark : .none
      
      return cell
  }
  
//MARK: - TableView Delegate Methods
  
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      //print(itemArray[indexPath.row])
      
    itemArray[indexPath.row].done = !itemArray[indexPath.row].done
      
      tableView.reloadData()
      
       tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
  }
  //MARK: - Add New Items
  
  @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
      
      var textField = UITextField()
  
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Todoey Item", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
      
      let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Item", style: .default) { (action) in
          //what will happen once the user clicks the add item
          
        let newItem = Item(itemTitle: textField.text!, itemStatus: false)
          
          self.itemArray.append(newItem)
          
          self.defaults.set(self.itemArray, forKey: "ToDoListArray")
          
          self.tableView.reloadData()
      }
      
      alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
          alertTextField.placeholder = "Create new item"
          textField = alertTextField
      }
      
      alert.addAction(action)
      
      present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your implementation is that you are using the same instance you are appending `newItem` instead of `newItem2` and `newItem3`

I would strongly advise using the below approach I will provide, it is safe and be customize easily

```
struct Item {
    var titleName: String?
    var description: String?

    init(titleName: String, description: String) {
       self.titleName = titleName
       self.description = description
    }
}

enum ItemOptions: Int, CaseIterable {
    case Find
    case Local
    case Search
 
    var title: String {
        switch self {
         case .Find: return "Find"
         case .Local: return "Local"
         case .Search: return "Search"
       }
    }

    var desciprion: String {
        switch self {
         case .Find: return "Find Desc"
         case .Local: return "Local Desc"
         case .Search: return "Search Desc"
         }
    }
}

class ToDoListViewController: UITableViewController {

    var itemArray = [Item]()

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    
       for item in ItemOptions.allCases {
           itemArray.append(Item(titleName: item.title, description: item.desciprion))
       }
    }
}
```

You can update the item Struct and add multiple values and only you change the enum either add maybe a new image, price.